# Dataprovider Mixing Up Values for Parallel Methods

Tags: parallel-processing, testng

I have two methods that use the same data provider. The Data provider reads an excel file to build the object to pass to the methods. However, when running the two methods in parallel, the data provider only passes back one variable for both methods.

I attempted to change the dataprovider variable names and object names but this did not work. I confirmed that the excel util function is working. Each if statement is called correctly in the data provider method, but it returns the wrong variable. How can I ensure that the data provider executes sequentially as to now mix up the variables?

Here is my Java class with testNG

```
public class dataprovidertest extends DriverMethods {

    @Test (groups = {"test"}, dataProvider = "datadriven")
    public void method1(String var1) throws Exception {
            System.out.println("method 1 variable: " + var1);
    }


    @Test (groups = {"test"}, dataProvider = "datadriven")
    public void method2(String var2) throws Exception {
        System.out.println("method 2 variable: " + var2);
    }

    @DataProvider (name = "datadriven")
    public Object[][] provideData(Method m) throws Exception{

        if(m.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("method1")) {
            String sTestCaseName1 = m.getName();
            Object[][] testObjArray1 = ExcelUtils.getTableArray("C:\\Users\\user\\dataprovidertest_TestData.xlsx", sTestCaseName1);
            return (testObjArray1);
        }

        if(m.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("method2")) {
            String sTestCaseName2 = m.getName();
            Object[][] testObjArray2 = ExcelUtils.getTableArray("C:\\Users\\user\\dataprovidertest_TestData.xlsx", sTestCaseName2);
            return (testObjArray2);
        }


        return null;
    }
```

Here is my xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
<suite name="Suite" parallel="methods" >

    <test thread-count="6" name="Test" parallel = "methods">
      <classes>
        <class name="cpq.dataprovidertest">
            <methods>
                <include name ="method1"/> 
                <include name ="method2"/>

            </methods>
     </class>
      </classes>
    </test> <!-- Test -->

</suite> <!-- Suite -->
```

Here is a description of my excel sheet:

Sheet "method1" has value "method1 var" 
Sheet "method2" has value "method2 var"

Currently, the output is:

```
[testng] method 2 variable: method2 var
[testng] method 1 variable: method2 var
```

or

```
  [testng] method 2 variable: method1 var
  [testng] method 1 variable: method1 var
```

How can I change this so it becomes:

```
  [testng] method 2 variable: method2 var
  [testng] method 1 variable: method1 var
```

Thanks!

i noticed that when I separate the two methods into class tags in the xml file, and run the tests parallel by classes, it works as expected:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
<suite name="Suite" data-provider-thread-count="2">

    <test thread-count="6" name="Test" parallel = "classes">
      <classes>
        <class name="cpq.dataprovidertest">
            <methods>
                <include name ="method1"/> 
            </methods>
        </class>
        <class name="cpq.dataprovidertest">
            <methods>
                <include name ="method2"/> 
            </methods>
        </class>
      </classes>
    </test> <!-- Test -->

</suite> <!-- Suite -->
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try with synchronized like

```
public synchronized Object[][]
```

Updated: add synchronized to method which collects data from sheet.

Comment: This worked! Adding it to my dataprovider class did not work, but adding synchronized to an outside method that deals with the excel sheet and returns the object solved the issue. Thanks so much!